# Magento 2 hide edit/delete/view link on grid based on condition

Tags: magento2, grid, uicomponent

I want to hide link for *edit/delete/view*  on grid based on
certain condition.

How can I do that with ui component

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I have done this using following way

In your grid listing file add below code

```
<actionsColumn name="actions" class="Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MerchantActions" sortOrder="10">
        <settings>
            <indexField>log_id</indexField>
            <resizeEnabled>false</resizeEnabled>
            <resizeDefaultWidth>107</resizeDefaultWidth>
        </settings>
    </actionsColumn>
```

I have added a class to show actions

add below code to `prepareDataSource` function

Vendor\Module\Ui\Component\Listing\Column\MerchantActions

```
public function prepareDataSource(array $dataSource)
{
    if (isset($dataSource['data']['items'])) {
        foreach ($dataSource['data']['items'] as &$item) {
            if (isset($item['log_id']) && empty($item['approval_status'])) {
                $item[$this->getData('name')] = ['edit' => ['href' => $this->urlBuilder->getUrl(static::URL_VIEW_PATH, ['log_id' => $item['log_id'],]), 'label' => __('View'),]];
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

I have added condition based on approval_status field , you can add accordingly

```
if (isset($item['log_id']) && empty($item['approval_status'])) {
```

hope this will help you :)